# Screen scraping Akamai's control panel using Mechanize for Ruby - Cookies Issue

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am attempting to screen scrape some data from Akamai's control panel, but I am having trouble while logging in to the page via mechanize for Ruby.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

url = 'http://control.akamai.com'
page = agent.get( url )

puts page.content
```

Upon examining the page, I find displayed:

```
"Cookie support has been disabled in your browser. Please enable cookies before continuing."
```

The fact that the page thinks I have cookies disabled prevents me from logging in. Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't used mechanize; I'm assuming it *does* handle HTTP-based cookies? Maybe the page is using javascript to set cookies?

Comment: The fact that there is such string in the HTML doesn't necessarily mean that it has been displayed to the user. I see that string in page source as well, but in browser I just see normal username and password form.

Comment: See my comments on Thiago's answer, but I believe you're correct in your assumption Mladen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify other user agent:

```
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
```

Or/And create a cookie manually:

```
cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new(key, value)
cookie.domain = '.akamai.com'
cookie.path = '/'
agent.cookie_jar.add(cookie)
```

For more info about Ruby Mechanize cookies, read this pages:

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Cookie.html
http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/CookieJar.html

Comment: Thanks Thiago. It's important to note that `agent.cookie_jar.add()` takes 2 args `uri = URI.parse("https://control.akamai.com")` then
`agent.cookie_jar.add(uri, cookie)`.

Thanks for getting me on the right track though, very helpful. -Brian